# How to resolve the 'not working stringify' in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have this code. When I click the button alert "hello" appears but further steps of Json stringify is not working.

```
       $('.maxi').click(function () {
            alert("hello");
            var str = "";
            x = $('#form_simple').serializeArray();
            str = JSON.stringify(x);

            $('#<%=hdnfld_stuseat.ClientID %>').val(str);


        });
```

asp.net:

```
<form id="form_simple" runat="server">

  .............codes..........
</form>
```

Browser side view source:
I have checked the browser side form name. It is as exactly as 'form_simple'.

[image: view source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. 
I had put the hiddenfield 'hdnfld_stuseat' in a panel which is currently hidden. 
So Jquery can't able to find 'hdnfld_stuseat' in the page to stringify. I changed the place of hiddenfield into the panel where the button (with cssclass='maxi') lies and that panel is not currently hidden. Silly mistake!